# How can I loop my program until Add to cart option available

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape Newegg's website to tell me when an Item can be added to cart option, the issue that I keep having is trying to loop the program until the "add to cart" available. I'm not sure how to get started with the loop.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def checker():
  
    my_url= 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=rtx++2070'

    #open connection
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    #parsing
    page_soup= soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':"item-container"})


    for container in containers:


        title_container = container.findAll('a',{'class':'item-title'})
        product_name = title_container[0].text

        link= container.find('a')['href']
            
            
        cart_container= container.findAll('div',{'class':'item-button-area'})
        cart= cart_container[0].text

        
            
        
while True:
    if "Add to cart" not in cart:
        checker()
        print('retrying')
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to get the list of items which are available (if item has Add to cart button) ?

Comment: yes, instead of looking at inventory It just checks the add to cart option

Answer (score 0):

You can make things easy by using xpath axes method. You can check this useful [site](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)
and here's the sample script you may use on your problem

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=rtx++2070")

# look for all "Add to cart button" then get it's attribute "title"
addToCartBtns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Add to cart']/ancestor::div[@class='item-action']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='item-info']/a")

for addToCartBtn in addToCartBtns:
    itemTitle = addToCartBtn.text
    print("\n"+itemTitle)
```